# How do I resolve the mixed content error: The page requested an insecure font 'https:'

Tags: fonts, mixed-content

My page ([page here](https://www.horizonhomes-samui.com/)) is suddenly displaying an unidentified mixed content error in the JavaScript console.  How can I resolve this error?  The error message is:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.horizonhomes-samui.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'https:'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Usually a mixed content error displays the a full URL of the offending insecure call.  But in this case it only displays `https:`.  The error references line one of my HTML source code, which isn't terribly illuminating.

Here are the additional troubleshooting steps I've taken:

- As a test, on my private dev site, I added an additional response header to my page to hopefully gain more insight into the mixed content error (per [these Google instructions](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content#finding_mixed_content_with_content_security_policy)), and loaded the page.  This time the JS console contained more information ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkQJj.jpg)).  Some of the new entries pointed to a file scripts.js, specifically, the line `var ret = test.offsetTop !== control.offsetTop;`  This is part of a function that seems to be related to the [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) JavaScript library ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwLpH.jpg)).  Other entries pointed more directly to the Modernizr library.
- I tried to carry out a search and replace of my database, but it wasn't very illuminating.  Specifically, used a plugin to execute a search and replace dry run. in which no changes are made.  It only generates a report of which database tables would be modified, and how many modifications would be done for each table.  I search for 'http:' and it returned ~1,200 hits, in several databse tables.
- I have the ability to carry out a text search of all my source code.  But what would I search for, `https:`?  That would return too many hits to review.
- The website is a WordPress site. As a test, I tried changing my theme from my child theme to my parent theme, and the issue went away.  So I guess that points to one of my child theme files as the culprit.
- I cannot replicate the issue in Firefox.  I have not been able to carry out an accurate test in IE or Edge because I am currently experiencing a separate, unrelated issue with those browsers.
- Looking at my source code, I see there are four similar calls to Google fonts, for the fonts: Questrial, Raleway, Montserrat, and Comfortaa. In the 'Network' tab of Chrome dev tools, it indicates that the Montserrat and Questrial fonts were loaded without issue ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYwg3.jpg)). But there were errors loading two additional, unknown fonts. Maybe these two unknowns are the Raleway and Comfortaa fonts.  As an additional test, I was able to omit the call to the 'Raleway' font ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zN7v.jpg)). But the page still displayed two mixed content errors related to fonts. I would have thought that omitting one of those font calls might remove one of the mixed content errors.

There have been no mixed content errors for the past ~3 years that I have been admin of this site.  To my knowledge, I've made no recent changes that would have caused this, other than updating a few plugins which I did a couple weeks ago.  I guess as a troubleshooting step I could try to ascertain what plugins I updated and roll them back to their previous versions.

Comment: Your html shows `<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100...' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`, change that to `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:...' rel='stylesheet'>` with an explicit protocol (and without the type. HTML5 prescribes the type _has_ to be understood as text/css unless your markup specifies a different type. Same for JS: don't specify a type unless the script is _not_ JS source code). Does it still complain after that change?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans OK got it.  I'm not entirely sure how to edit those calls right now.  I'll have to research that.  As an side though, looking at my source code, I see there are four similar calls to Google fonts, for the fonts:  Questrial, Raleway, Montserrat, and Comfortaa.  In the 'Network' tab of Chrome dev tools, it indicates that the Montserrat and Questrial fonts were loaded without issue (screenshot:  https://imgur.com/a/SyCt5Ot).  But there were errors loading two additional, unknown fonts.  Maybe these two unknowns are the Raleway and Comfortaa fonts.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Also, as a test, I was able to omit the call to the 'Raleway' font (screenshot:  https://imgur.com/hrwVbzE).  But the page still displayed two mixed content errors related to fonts.  I would have thought that omitting one of those font calls might remove one of the mixed content errors :-/

Comment: Better to put that information in your question, since that's information that any potential question-answerer should probably know. Also worth trying more than one browser to see what the different ones report (sometimes you get better reporting out of edge or firefox or chrome compared to the others).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans OK good ideas. I tested on Firefox and could *not* replicate the issue.  I'm unfortunately having separate issues with Edge/IE, so I haven't really been able to accurately test on those.  I added all new info to my original question. Odd that the issue is not present in IE.  Maybe I can now post to a Chrome-specific forum for assistance.

Comment: Don't bother with IE: it is deprecated and isn't going to give any sensible errors for modern problems.

Comment: Hi, I think this might be a bug in Chromium itself. We've been experiencing it on BBC Sport for a while now. And I've found the exact build of Chrome it was introduced in. I have raised a bug here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=902115 - hopefully they'll provide some feedback shortly. Thanks, this is the first other occurrence I've seen of it online.

Comment: @SimonScarfe OK interesting.  I'll try to monitor that other thread. If there's a resolution in that thread, let's one of us try to post it here as well.  (PS I also left a comment in that other thread)